# Password alternatives in the cryptography

Tags: cryptography, quantum-computation

All the modern informational systems are based on a password concept. The password idea is the cornerstone of contemporary cryptography as well.
Assume that quantum computers can and will succeed in any "brute-force attack" in the next decade. It means that the fundamental idea of cryptography in non-quantum computing must be reconsidered.
Where can I find the information about possible strategic alternatives to passwords in the information systems?

Comment: 1.You might want to ask this on security.stackexchange instead since you are less looking for a mathematical reasoning and more for security advice on how to make a system quantum-proof. 

2. tldr, quantum computing will not invalidate "passwords" (I assume by password you mean security key as in assymetric or symmetric key), though it may succeed to "brute-force" (it’s not really brute-force) some cryptographic algorithms, there exist "post-quantum" algorithms that quantum computers are no better than normal computers against.

Comment: As a starter, you could look [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean when referring to the 'password concept', but my perception is that in  many areas password based authentication is in the process of being replaced by other means (asymmetric cryptography, biometric methods like face recognition, ...).

Comment: @Moo: love it! Thank you!